# Extension on Google Chrome to change YouTube's new video size?

Tags: chrome, youtube

On YouTube there is (well it's not annoying) but they have this new default video size which looks a bit like this or you can view the full image [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/74OyX.jpg)

[image]

Long story short, is there a way to change the default video size to how it use to look like before which was smaller?

Any ideas/suggestions for a Google Chrome Extension that can do this?

Comment: Sit tight, I'll develop one for ya

Answer (score 2):

[Magic Actions for YouTube](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/magic-actions-for-youtube/abjcfabbhafbcdfjoecdgepllmpfceif) can:
AutoHD feature - start play all YouTube™ videos in HD
+ Highres > HD1440p > HD1080p > HD720p > 480p > 360p > 240p > 144p
and a lot more.

What chrome looks like with the extension enabled and a fixed size selected on my system:
[image]

Comment: I want it to look like this again > http://web.archive.org/watch?v=bLBSoC_2IY8

Comment: That link doesn't work for me.

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/HpJKc.jpg

Comment: I ended up just taking a snapshot of what I want youtube to look like again.

Comment: Install the extension and configure it to use a fixed size video window on start up, try 480 but it depends on your screen size and browser position and you should get it.  Added example to answer.